# Displaying group items in a panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem displaying items inside a panel, that is attached to dataflow layout, the panel has label, textbox, button, checkbox and image, when I run the program only the image disaplys even though I have set the postion of each control in the panel, and the panel is looped from the database inside the dataflow layout control, also, when i try to change the size of the panel nothing displays.

I just want someone to point to the right direction , any help is appreciated

thank you

what I have done do far:

```
foreach ("looped according to the database")
            {
                Panel pan = new Panel();
                PictureBox img = new PictureBox();
                Button btn = new Button();
                Label house = new Label();
                TextBox Street = new TextBox();
                CheckBox check = new CheckBox();

                pan.Location = new Point();
                pan.Size = new System.Drawing.Size();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                img .Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                img .Tag = Product.ID;
                img .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                img .Location = new System.Drawing.Point();
                img .Size = new System.Drawing.Size();
                img .TabIndex = 0;
                house .Text = Product.Name;
                house .Location = new System.Drawing.Point();
                house .Size = new System.Drawing.Size();
                house .AutoSize = true;
                house .TabIndex = 1;
                Street.Location = new System.Drawing.Point();
                Street.Size = new System.Drawing.Size();
                Street.TabIndex = 2;
                btn.Text = "info";
                btn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size();
                btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point();
                btn.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                btn.TabIndex = 2;
                pan.Controls.Add(img);
            pan.Controls.Add(check);
                pan.Controls.Add(House);
                pan .Controls.Add(Street);
                pan.Controls.Add(btn);
                this.ProductsFlowPanel.Controls.Add(pan);


            }
        }
```

I am trying to achieve something similar to this;
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szjMd.png)

Comment: Line `pan = new Point();` will not even compile, because `pan` is already declared as variable of type `Panel`

Comment: this was my reference when I create the form, can please take a look  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples

Comment: Line `Panel pan = new Panel();` - create instance of type `Panel`. Your line `pan = new Point();` will try set new instance of `Point` to `pan` - it is impossible in C# because `pan` is already declared as type of `Panel`. Obviously you tried to write `pan.Location = new Point()`

Comment: pan.Location = new Point() this was my code I think by mistake I deleted it, the problem still persists, do have any idea what could cause the problem, if not please take look at the image I attached maybe you could have a different idea to achieve that :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I noticed,

The panel object you created at the start is reassigned on line 10 and 11:

```
Panel pan = new Panel();
...
pan = new Point(); //probably remove this
pan = new System.Drawing.Size(); //and this
```

In addition, the size and position of all your controls is just empty points and sizes, eg:

```
img .Location = new System.Drawing.Point();
img .Size = new System.Drawing.Size();
```

It should probably be something more like this:

```
img .Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10,10);
img .Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50,50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are some things in your code which are definitely wrong. I don't know if that's causing the problem, but this is the direction you asked for.

The syntax: `something x = new something();` is used to create an object of `something`

The prerequisite for this is that the `something()` class should be reachable.

Now let's break this down `something x;` <-- this declares `something` as `x`

`x = new something()` <-- this initiates `x` to the `something` object.

What you're doing in your code is:

```
    Panel pan = new Panel(); //pan is now an object of `Panel()` class.
    pan = new Point(); //pan is now an object of `Point()` class.
    pan = new System.Drawing.Size(); //pan is now an object of `System.Drawing.Size()` class.
```

Now, in C#, the last declaration is accepted. So basically, `pan` isn't an object of the `Panel` class anymore. Which means your logic for panel won't work.

Another thing I noticed is that the size and position of all your controls is just empty points and sizes.

It should be something like:

```
img .Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50,50);
img .Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100,100);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: okay, thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question, but I want to change the position of the pan using points, also change the size, from my research I found that this is the way to do it, but do you know of any way I could change the size and the position without using the code above??

Comment: @SSSS I didn't exactly get what you need to do.

Comment: pan = new Point();  
 pan = new System.Drawing.Size();                                                                     I want to change the size do know of any way other than the these to line to do that?? I searched but could not find anything

Comment: @SSSS Sorry mate, that's all I know about panels and points. I strongly believe that you've been misguided. I could help you out better if you provide more information on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have added image, could you please take a look :)